# How Angular dependency injection mechanism does work?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to understand the mechanism behind Angular/NestJs dependency injection.

when a Typescript class is built, the type of its parameters is lost. example:

```
type Dependency1 = {};
type Dependency2 = {};

class X {
    constructor(dependency: Dependency1){}
}
```

become

```
"use strict";
class X {
    constructor(dependency) { }
}
```

How Angular Injector can replace the `dependency` parameter with the right instance of the Dependency class?

Comment: angular compiler reads this type and adds an injection token to class metadata, this token is then requested from the appropriate injector to get an instance of what is provided by that token.

Comment: @Andrei That's mean that the angular compiler read my component as a string (before transforming it into a js file) and add an injection token to a metadata class inside my component class for each parameter of my component constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If angular's is anything like Nest's DI resolution (which it should be similar, Nest was inspired by Angular), then what's being used if the function's name (i.e. the class's name). As classes are functions in JavaScript, and all functions have a `.name` property, that's what is being used to get the injection token and checked back against the module container for the same token (same class or custom provider).